# InputFile component problem with image upload

Tags: .net, blazor, blazorinputfile

What's wrong with InputFile in Blazor?

> (Edit: "what's wrong with my implementation of InputFile, as someone
> pointed out in the comment")

this was the actual image I'm trying to upload,
[image]

and this is the resulting display, after uploading; the image is cropped. On top of that, the application also stops working all of a sudden.

[image]

and here's the piece of code what is called on the `OnChange` event of the `InputFile`

```
    async Task OnFileChange(InputFileChangeEventArgs e) {
        const string format = "image/png";
        var resizedImage = await e.File.RequestImageFileAsync(format, 512, 512);
        var buffer = new byte[resizedImage.Size];
        await resizedImage.OpenReadStream().ReadAsync(buffer);
        imageBase64 = $"data:{format};base64,{Convert.ToBase64String(buffer)}";
      }
```

the usual tutorials use 200 or 256 as image size, though all I did was just double the value[image], which is still below the threshold of the `RequestImageFileAsync` method which is `512000`

**Edit 1:**
this is the snippet of the button that triggers the InputFile

```
<MudFab HtmlTag="label" Size="Size.Small" Color="Color.Primary" StartIcon="@Icons.Filled.CloudUpload" for="fileInput" />
```

here's the snippet of the InputFile on the razor page.

```
<InputFile id="fileInput" OnChange="OnFileChange" hidden multiple accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png" />
```

here's the image component displaying the image

```
<MudImage ObjectFit="ObjectFit.ScaleDown" Src="@imageBase64" Elevation="25"  Class="rounded my-2"></MudImage>
```

note that I'm indeed using Mudblazor, but I don't think that is of any significance. I tried it on vanilla HTML but still the same issue.

I have slimmed the code so if you put it together, the razor page should look like this:

```
@page "/tryImage"

<PageTitle>Try Image</PageTitle>

<InputFile id="fileInput" OnChange="OnFileChange" hidden multiple accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png" />
<MudImage ObjectFit="ObjectFit.ScaleDown" Src="@imageBase64" Elevation="25"  Class="rounded my-2"></MudImage>
<MudFab HtmlTag="label" Size="Size.Small" Color="Color.Primary" StartIcon="@Icons.Filled.CloudUpload" for="fileInput" />


@code {
    private string? imageBase64;
    async Task OnFileChange(InputFileChangeEventArgs e) {
        const string format = "image/png";
        var resizedImage = await e.File.RequestImageFileAsync(format, 512, 512);
        var buffer = new byte[resizedImage.Size];
        await resizedImage.OpenReadStream().ReadAsync(buffer);
        imageBase64 = $"data:{format};base64,{Convert.ToBase64String(buffer)}";
      }
}
```

**Edit 2:**
Or is it possible that the error has something to do with large images in conflict with `RequestImageFileAsync` since the sample image I showed above is about 1.2 MB and has dimensions of 4929x3286?

Comment: "What's wrong with InputFile in Blazor? this was the actual image I'm trying to upload" Almost certainly nothing, it's your code.  Without more code, your question is impossible to answer.  That looks like MudBlazor?

Comment: Woah, kinda passive-aggressive comment don't you think? you could have said it nicer. Yes, it's mudblazor, but I don't know if it's relevant, I tried using it without mudblazor and still the same issue. I don't know what kind of code you are looking for, that's the only code that has any relationship with InputFile, but ok, I'll try to add the razor if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis now I have edited the questions please enlighten me with the "Almost certainly, it's your code" comment you made please. thank you very much.

Comment: [Polite] No malice intended :-), but many question askers think that the problem is caused by a bug, when in 99+% of the cases it's their code.  Your question implied that.  Your original question was light on detail and you never mentioned MudBlazor which you were obviously using and may be pertinent to the problem.  It's hard for people to help questioners when they don't provide enough detail.

Comment: I never intended to say that it was a bug though. I may have expressed my question incorrectly, let me apologize for that, not my 1st language by the way. I skipped mudblazor thinking that it would just cause confusion because like I said, I did use the InputFile the same way without Mudblazor and the cropped image persisted. Nevertheless, I have added my code if it might help.

Comment: "On top of that, the application also stops working all of a sudden." Do you have any error/exception in your browser console? Or would this be because you would block Blazor UI with a long task?

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine, the thing is I did not receive any error when I looked at the Output window of VS. I did not see any error even when I inspect the running application after it stopped working. I could like the buttons but no responses though, It felt like a background task is running so I just let it run for 5 mins, but it never went away, or I should be expecting it to produce errors at the point, but no luck. I just stop working.

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine I also did some debugging, and all of the processes finished properly on the OnFileChange method. after the image is loaded on the UI, that is when I get the freezing of the components. I also tried removing all of the other parts of the application leaving just the upload image and I still have the same error.

Comment: Is it Blazor WebAssembly?

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine I tried on both blazor wasm and server and i got the same result

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine my main app was in blazor server, I did retest the application using fewer codes in Blazor wasm (just the image upload process) and the problem seem went away. I don't know why it does not work with blazor server. thanks anyway, I will go for wasm all the way.

Comment: I wonder if you are hitting a size limit - either for the `data` url or even for the JS interop between Blazor and the browser - setting an attribute to the base64 encoded image maybe? Try smaller images to see if that is what is happening. You might be better off generating a `dataUrl` blob for the image in JS and using that

Comment: @MisterMagoo I also think it's the size that's the issue; reducing the `RequestImageFileAsync` image size produces no error, I haven't tested smaller images, but I guess it will work fine. I think it's the limitation on the JS Interop. let me try what you suggested. But I might stick with Wasm since, there are no issues at all.

Comment: This is a duplicated, here is the sam question and solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70790385/ibrowserfile-fromimagefileasync-incomplete-image

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IBrowserFile FromIMageFileAsync incomplete image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70790385/ibrowserfile-fromimagefileasync-incomplete-image)

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same problem on Blazor server side. It wasn't cause by maximum size of the file. No errors, app stuck and only reloading the page helps
I changed this code:

```
var resized = await browseFile.RequestImageFileAsync(browseFile.ContentType, maxWidth: 500, maxHeight: 800);
var buffer = new byte[resized.Size];
await resized.OpenReadStream(maxAllowedSize: 5120000).ReadAsync(buffer); //500KB
var fileString = $"data:{browseFile.ContentType};base64,{Convert.ToBase64String(buffer)}";
```

to:

```
using MemoryStream ms = new();
var resized = await browseFile.RequestImageFileAsync(browseFile.ContentType, maxWidth: 500, maxHeight: 800);
using Stream fileStream = resized.OpenReadStream(); 
await fileStream.CopyToAsync(ms);
                
var fileString = $"data:{browseFile.ContentType};base64,{Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray())}";
```

and it works :-) 
I still don't know where the cause was. If anyone figures it out, let me know

Comment: Thanks man, you saved hours of my life - great.

Answer (score 0):

This works in this example https://youtu.be/bQ6D4VFMxc4
But it works on net5.0
The problem occurs on net6.0

So I made some changes.

Commented whole program.cs file and copied program.cs and startup.cs from net5.0

In project file I commented

```
<!--<ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>-->
```

In Layout.cshtml

Commented

```
@*<component type="typeof(HeadOutlet)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />*@
```

and copied form net5.0 host.chtml

```
<component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
```

to body section before @RenderBody.

And it works but this is not solution. If anybody has idea how to make this work in net6.00 or workaround please let me know.